# Generating mathematical vectors for math library unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, math, vector, template-meta-programming

I am attempting to unit test some functions on my Vector (as in math vector) class:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct Vector {
    std::array<T, N> data;
    ...
    constexpr inline auto magnitude2() const noexcept -> T {...}
    ...
}
```

I have written a type parameterized unit test for this (over both T and N) as follows (shown simplified):

```
TYPED_TEST(VectorTestFixture, magnitude2) {
    using T = ...;  // Get from gtest
    static constexpr auto N = ...;  // Get from gtest

    auto expected = T{};
    auto vec = Vector<T, N>{};

    for (auto i = 0u; i < N; ++i) {
        auto x = static_cast<T>(i);
        vec[i] = x;

        expected += x * x;
    }

    ASSERT_EQ(vec.magnitude2(), expected);
}
```

This dynamically creates a vector from incrementing integers. E.g. {0, 1, 2, 3} or {0, 1, 2}.
It then compares magnitude2 on this vector to a dynamically determined expected value.

This seems counter to the idea of TDD though, as the test basically has the same logic as the code being tested. Also, it does not scale well with other operations (like add).

Potentially I could write test cases for each vector size manually, and then convert to each possible type, but that's certainly not very elegant.

I would like to avoid manually writing test cases for the different combinations of type and size. Does anyone have ideas on an approach for generating test cases here?

Comment: _"Potentially I could write test cases for each vector size manually, and then convert to each possible type, but that's certainly not very elegant"_ - I find that reasoning .... perfect. I personally do not wish to contort "nice" code just to make it "testable".

Comment: Try testing the mathematical properties, like it should never be negative, it's zero only if all the components are zero and so on (the magnitude of the sum of two vector is less than or equal to the sum of the magnitudes). Pick some random points on a sphere and check if the magnitude is (almost) equal to the radius.

Comment: @Bob__ Interesting idea. Maybe that could be used in combination with some exact test cases for a couple of type and size combinations.